# Java: Two classes with nearly identical methods using two different enums; possible to avoid redundancy? (static methods everywhere)

Tags: java, enums, refactoring, uml, eclipse-emf

I have two enums describing two UML profiles (meaning they define stereotypes that the profiles contain).

I also have two utility classes featuring nearly identical methods working on each of the profiles.

Example:

```
public static List<Element> getStereotypedElements(final InsertProfileHere stereo, final Package pkg) {
    List<Element> extendedElements = new ArrayList<Element>();      
    if (isProfileApplied(pkg)) {
        if (hasStereotype(stereo, pkg)) {
            extendedElements.add(pkg);
        }
        extendedElements.addAll(getStereotypedElements(stereo, pkg.allOwnedElements()));
    }
    return extendedElements;
}
```

,where **InsertProfileHere** can be replaced with each of the two profile enums.

If anyone is interested, this method uses the Eclipse Modeling Framework or rather the UML2 metamodel implementation in EMF.

Anyway, I want to merge the two utility classes to avoid redundant code.

I've tried:

- a super interface for the two profiles

  - didn't work because of static methods
- an abstract class for the Utility classes

  - didn't work because of static methods
- encapsulating the profile enums in a class

Each didn't work for one or another reason.

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT:

An example for another utility method:

```
public static boolean hasStereotype(
    final InsertProfileHere stereo, final Element elem) {
    for (Stereotype appliedStereo : elem.getAppliedStereotypes()) {
        if (stereo == null) {
            if (InsertProfileHere.contains(appliedStereo)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (stereo.isEqual(appliedStereo)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT2: And for good measure part of the implementation of the profile enum

```
public enum Profile1 { 

STEREOTYPE1 ("readable stereotype1 name"),
STEREOTYPE2 ("readable stereotype2 name"),
STEREOTYPE3 ("readable stereotype3 name"),

public static final String PROFILE_NAME = "NameOfProfile";

private final String readableName;

private Profile1(final String newName) {
    readableName = newName;
}

public static Profile1 getValue(final String name) {
    for (Profile1 type : Profile1.values()) {
        if (type.toString().equals(name)) {
            return type;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean contains(Stereotype stereotype) {
    return (stereotype.getProfile().
            getDefinition().getNsURI().contains(PROFILE_NAME));
}
```

Comment: Why two enums? If we're fundamentally talking Category and Subcategory then just whack the cartesian product in one Enum, or (better still IMHO) just wear the "near duplicate" code... it's only one (short) method, yes?

Comment: What didn't work when your Enums implemented the same interface?

Comment: @1: Not quite, there are several methods in the Utility class, I only posted one example.

Comment: @2: The enums have static methods getValue(String), which returns the appropriate enum constant, and contains(Stereotype), which checks if the given Stereotype is part of the profile. Using an interface, I couldn't use static methods.

Comment: @1: Also, I don't know if I understand you right, but the two profiles don't contain the same stereotypes.

Answer (score 1):

Let the two enums implement a common interface, and use this interface in the (now unified) utility class. Or, better yet, move the methods from the utility class to the interface.

```
interface Stereotype {
  public boolean hasStereotype(Package pkg);
  public List<Element> getStereotypedElementes(Package pkg);
}

 enum Enum1 implements Stereotype {

   FOO("com.foo"), BAR("com.bar");

   Enum1(String packagename) {
     this.packagename=packagename;
   }

   private String packagename;

  @Override
  public boolean hasStereotype(Package pkg) {
    return pkg.getName().equals(packagename);
  }

  @Override
  public List<Element> getStereotypedElementes(Package pkg) {
    ...
  }

}

 enum Enum2 implements Stereotype {
   ...
 }


public class Foo {
  static List<Element> getStereotypedElements(final Stereotype stereo, final Package pkg) {
    List<Element> extendedElements = new ArrayList<Element>();      
    if (isProfileApplied(pkg)) {
        if (stereo.hasStereotype(pkg)) {
            extendedElements.add(pkg);
        }
        extendedElements.addAll(stereo.getStereotypedElements(pkg.allOwnedElements()));
    }
    return extendedElements;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, in my mind I replace "Stereotype" with "UMLProfile". hasStereotype(Package) means that I can ask every instance of the profile enum if a package has this stereotype. Would this also work if I wanted a static method hasStereotype which checks if the Package contains any of the profile stereotypes?

Answer (score 0):

Use common interface as in example below.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class EnumeInteraceTest
{
    public interface ICorolsEnum
    {
        public Color getColor();
    }
    public enum Colors1 implements ICorolsEnum
    {
        MAGENTA(Color.MAGENTA),
        PINK(Color.PINK);
        private Color color;

        private Colors1(Color color)
        {
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public Color getColor()
        {
            return color;
        }
    }
    public enum Colors2 implements ICorolsEnum
    {
        GREEN(Color.GREEN),
        BLUE(Color.BLUE);
        private Color color;

        private Colors2(Color color)
        {
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public Color getColor()
        {
            return color;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ICorolsEnum ice1 = Colors1.MAGENTA;
        System.out.println(ice1.getColor());
        ICorolsEnum ice2 = Colors2.GREEN;
        System.out.println(ice2.getColor());
    }
}
```